# Fallback to Smarty2 on Prestashop 1.5

Tags: smarty, prestashop

Is there a way to user smarty2 instead of smarty3 in Prestashop 1.5 ? I have updated from 1.2.5 and the theme is ruined.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the Backward Compatility feature of Smarty.

In the file "/config/smarty.config.inc.php", replace :

```
require_once(_PS_SMARTY_DIR_.'Smarty.class.php');
global $smarty;
$smarty = new Smarty();
```

by

```
require_once(_PS_SMARTY_DIR_.'SmartyBC.class.php');
global $smarty;
$smarty = new SmartyBC();
```

Comment: Didn't help. Tried to fix all the includes but now I get additional errors like `"{assign var=imageIds value=`$product-&gt;id`-`$image.id_image`}"`

Comment: Can you share the template name & its content ?

Comment: There are plenty of changes in Smarty3 for which I know no backwards compatibility layer. Obviously, @VitKos could upgrade all the template files manually, but I think the original question is a useful one: some way of forcing the new application to use the old Smarty.